# Regex for phone numbers

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to catch the phone number from a text using regex.

Examples:

I have this regex which finds the phone number very well:
`^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$`

and it catches all the numbers below well.

But I cannot catch the "tel.", "tlf", "mobil:", etc that could be before the number. And also, if another letter comes after the last digit, it doesn't take number anymore, but it should.

These examples are not covered:

```
tel.: +45 09827374, +45 89895867, some kind of text... 
mobil: +45 20802020, +45 20802001,
tlf.: +45 5555 1212 
tlf: +4567890202Girrafe
```

If helpful, I found this regex:
`'\btlf\b\D*([\d\s]+\d)'` which can extract the number and the tlf and also stop before it finds a new character which is represented by a letter.

So I tried to combine them and I obtained this but it doesn't work:
`\b(tlf|mobil|telephone|mobile|tel)\b\D*(^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$)`

Expected output:

- for input: `"tel.: +45 09827374, +45 89895867, some kind of text..."` --> output: `"tel.: +45 09827374" and "+45 89895867"`
- for input: `"mobil: +45 20802020, +45 20802001,"` --> output: `"mobil: +45 20802020"` and `"+45 20802001"` or `"mobil: +45 20802020, +45 20802001"` is ok too
- for input: `"tlf +45 5555 1212"` --> output:  `"tlf +45 5555 1212"`
- for input: `"tlf: +4567890202Girrafe"` --> output: `"tlf: +4567890202"`
- for input:  `"+4567890202"` --> output: `"+4567890202"`

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the expected outcomes for examples.

Comment: Try `(?:\b(tlf|mobil|telephone|mobile|tel)\b)?[^\w\n]*((?:\(\+45\)|\+45)?\s*\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/XiYYkZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you! just one little thing: why does it also take everything what's before "tel"? https://regex101.com/r/H1Q1Je/1 - test: fresh air, tel.: +45 30300303, +45 20202020 - how to edit the regex so it won't take the words before tel? i tried with removing the "?:" from the beginning but didn't work :(

Comment: @AriadneR. If you don't want that, you can be more specific about what can be after the tel. like this https://regex101.com/r/mW6rPV/1 Or as a single match without groups https://regex101.com/r/Ep0nWs/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the full match only:

```
(?:\b(?:tlf|mobile?|tel(?:ephone)?)[.:\s]+)?(?:\(\+45\)|\+45)?\s*\d{2}(?:\s?\d{2}){3}(?!\d)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
  - `(?:tlf|mobile?|tel(?:ephone)?)` match one of the alternatives
  - `[.:\s]+` match 1+ occurrences of either `.` `:`  or a whitespace char
- `)?` Close the on capture group and make it optional
- `(?:\(\+45\)|\+45)?` Optionally match either `+45` or `(+45)`
- `\s*\d{2}(?:\s?\d{2}){3}` Match 3 times 2 digits with an optional whitespace char in between
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead, assert not a digit directly to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5X0A6F/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a single regexp, you could match the `tel:` etc. text first and then just match every phone number, e.g. using GNU awk and POSIX EREs instead of PCREs:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[+]45[[:space:]]*[0-9][0-9[:space:]]+[0-9]' '
    match($0,/^(tel|mobil|tlf)\.?:/,a) {
        printf "%s ", a[0]
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            print $i
        }
    }
' file
tel.: +45 09827374
+45 89895867
mobil: +45 20802020
+45 20802001
tlf.: +45 5555 1212
tlf: +4567890202
```

You can do the same with any awk with just a bit more code:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^(tel|mobil|tlf)\.?:/) {
    printf "%s ", substr($0,1,RLENGTH)
    while ( match($0,/[+]45[ \t]*[0-9][[0-9 \t]+[0-9]/) ) {
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}' file
tel.: +45 09827374
+45 89895867
mobil: +45 20802020
+45 20802001
tlf.: +45 5555 1212
tlf: +4567890202
```

and I'm sure you could do the same in python, perl, ruby or whatever similar tool you like.

IMO it's better to have a couple of small, simple regexps in your code than one lone, complicated one.